# node.js Http Request assistance

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm having a difficult time as a novice figuring out why this won't send. I'm sure it's quite simple, I'm just having a hard time figuring it out on my end.

```
`/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  // let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  // res.status(200).send(message);
  // console.log(req.body.payload) ~ works fine
  var paylord = JSON.parse(req.body.payload);
  // console.log(paylord.type);

  var slackMessage = {
        "text": "Thanks for your request, we'll process it and get back to you.",
        "response_type": "ephemeral"
  }

  var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  payload: JSON.stringify(slackMessage)
};

res.status(200).send(paylord.request_url, options)
};
```

Comment: Can you please share the logging output on the console?

Comment: Could you also share how you are calling and reading the result of this function?